# Drawing a large set of Graphics3D cylinders provided a set of cylinder specifications in a list

Tags: graphics3d, map

I'd like to draw a large number of 3D cylinders using `Graphics3D`.  My list specifying the cylinders has elements that look like the following:

```
{ {{{p1x1, p1y1, p1z1}, {p2x1, p2y1, p2z1}},r1}, {{{p1x2, p1y2, p1z2}, {p2x2, p2y2, p2z2}},r2}, {{{p1x3, p1y3, p1z3}, {p2x3, p2y3, p2z3}},r3}, ...}
```

Here, the first subelement, e.g. `{{p1x1, p1y1, p1z1}, {p2x1, p2y1, p2z1}}`, specifies the coordinates for the two end-points of the cylinder, and the the second subelement, e.g. `r1` or `r2`, specifies the radius of the specific cylinder.

Is there a way to use mapping to draw all of these cylinders with a condensed line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `/@` does it! Form $1500$ random cylinders from data.

```
cyildat =Table[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], RandomReal[5]}, {1500}];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None],Directive[Opacity@RandomReal[{.4, .9}], Hue[RandomReal[]]], 
Cylinder[First@#, Last@#]} & /@ cyildat,(* Map on your data *)
Boxed -> False,ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, this code is causing _Mathematica_ 9.0.1 to crash on a mid-2013 MacBook Air running OS X 10.9 (Mavericks). It works, though, if I make the number of cylinders smaller. (Haven't determined how small before it starts crashing.) Anyone else experiencing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html):

```
Cylinder @@@ {{{{p1x1, p1y1, p1z1}, {p2x1, p2y1, p2z1}}, 
   r1}, {{{p1x2, p1y2, p1z2}, {p2x2, p2y2, p2z2}}, 
   r2}, {{{p1x3, p1y3, p1z3}, {p2x3, p2y3, p2z3}}, r3}}

(* {Cylinder[{{p1x1, p1y1, p1z1}, {p2x1, p2y1, p2z1}}, r1], 
 Cylinder[{{p1x2, p1y2, p1z2}, {p2x2, p2y2, p2z2}}, r2], 
 Cylinder[{{p1x3, p1y3, p1z3}, {p2x3, p2y3, p2z3}}, r3]} *)
```