# generating randomly oriented non-intersecting cylinders

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, random, geometry

I could not find anything relevant with "googling" (only [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/115624-generating-randomly-oriented-non-intersecting-cylinders-in-a-unit-cell))

I can create a set of randomly oriented cylinders (code found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/drawing-a-large-set-of-graphics3d-cylinders-provided-a-set-of-cylinder-specifica/36990#36990))

```
cylinders = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], RandomReal[5]}, {100}];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
    Directive[Opacity@RandomReal[{.4, .9}], Hue[RandomReal[]]], 
    Cylinder[First@#, Last@#]} & /@ cylinders, Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

How can we keep the cylinders that they do not intersect each other?

Comment: Do all the cylinders have the same radius?

Comment: @J.M. No, unfortunately. The radius is controlled by `RandomReal[5]` in `Table[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], RandomReal[5]}, {100}]`.

Comment: You can adapt the rejection method used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98513) to this case; all you need is a way to find the distance between two line segments, such as the routine in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85903).

Comment: Ok. I will try to do on my own and post an answer. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @J.M. If I understand correctly, I will use the routine in order to generate no intersecting line segments which will be axes of cylinders?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer replaces an earlier one that deleted only some of the intersecting cylinders.  (My thanks to [paw](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4539/paw) for pointing this out.)  It also is much faster.

The square of the distance between points at `p1` and `p2` is

```
p1.p1 + p2.p2 - 2 p1.p2
```

and a cylinder axis can be parameterized by `pi + dp t`, where `pi` is one end of the axis, `dp` is the vector from `pi` to the other end of the axis, and `0 < t < 1`.  Thus, the parameterized square of the distance between points on the axes of two cylinders is

```
((p1.p1 + p2.p2 - 2 p1.p2) /. {p1 -> p1i + dp1 t1, p2 -> p2i + dp2 t2}) // tf // Expand
(* p1i.p1i - 2 p1i.p2i + p1i.(dp1 t1) - 2 p1i.(dp2 t2) + p2i.p2i + 
   p2i.(dp2 t2) + (dp1 t1).p1i - 2 (dp1 t1).p2i + (dp1 t1).(dp1 t1) - 
   2 (dp1 t1).(dp2 t2) + (dp2 t2).p2i + (dp2 t2).(dp2 t2) *)
```

where

```
tf[e_] := e /. Dot[z1_ + z2_, z3_ + z4_] -> 
    Dot[z1, z3] + Dot[z2, z3] + Dot[z1, z4] + Dot[z2, z4]
```

is used to distribute `Dot` over `Plus`.  (`FunctionExpand` does not do so.)  Next, the scalars `t1` and `t2` need to be factored from `Dot`.

```
Map[# /. z_ :> (z /. t1 -> 1) t1^Count[z, t1, 4] &, 
    Map[# /. z_ :> (z /. t2 -> 1) t2^Count[z, t2, 4] &, %]]
(* t1^2 dp1.dp1 - 2 t1 t2 dp1.dp2 + t1 dp1.p1i - 2 t1 dp1.p2i + t2^2 dp2.dp2 + 
   t2 dp2.p2i + t1 p1i.dp1 - 2 t2 p1i.dp2 + p1i.p1i - 2 p1i.p2i + t2 p2i.dp2 + p2i.p2i *)
```

Finally, `t1` and `t2` that minimize this quantity are obtained

```
FullSimplify[Solve[{D[%, t1] == 0, D[%, t2] == 0}, {t1, t2}], 
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf1}]
(* {{t1 -> (dp2.dp1 (-dp2.p1i + dp2.p2i) + 
       dp2.dp2 (p1i.dp1 - p2i.dp1))/((dp1.dp2)^2 - dp1.dp1 dp2.dp2), 
     t2 -> (dp1.dp1 (-dp2.p1i + dp2.p2i) + 
       dp2.dp1 (p1i.dp1 - p2i.dp1))/((dp1.dp2)^2 - dp1.dp1 dp2.dp2)}} *)
```

where

```
tf1[e_] := e /. Dot[z1_, z2_] -> Dot[z2, z1]
```

A function determining the distance between two cylinders can be written, based on this result.

```
int[cyl1_, cyl2_] := 
    Module[{p1i = cyl1[[1, 1]], dp1 = cyl1[[1, 2]] - cyl1[[1, 1]], r1 = cyl1[[2]], 
        p2i = cyl2[[1, 1]], dp2 = cyl2[[1, 2]] - cyl2[[1, 1]], r2 = cyl2[[2]], 
        loc, t1, t2}, loc = {t1 -> (dp2.dp1 (-dp2.p1i + dp2.p2i) + 
        dp2.dp2 (p1i.dp1 - p2i.dp1))/((dp1.dp2)^2 - dp1.dp1 dp2.dp2), 
        t2 -> (dp1.dp1 (-dp2.p1i + dp2.p2i) + 
        dp2.dp1 (p1i.dp1 - p2i.dp1))/((dp1.dp2)^2 - dp1.dp1 dp2.dp2)};
        (-r2/Norm[dp2] < (t1 /. loc) < 1 + r2/Norm[dp2]) &&
        (-r1/Norm[dp1] < (t2 /. loc) < 1 + r1/Norm[dp1]) && 
        ((t1^2 dp1.dp1 - 2 t1 t2 dp1.dp2 + t1 dp1.p1i - 2 t1 dp1.p2i + t2^2 dp2.dp2 + 
        t2 dp2.p2i + t1 p1i.dp1 - 2 t2 p1i.dp2 + p1i.p1i - 2 p1i.p2i + t2 p2i.dp2 +
        p2i.p2i) /. loc) < (r1 + r2)^2]
```

The conditions `(-r2/Norm[dp2] < (t1 /. loc) < 1 + r2/Norm[dp2])` and similarly for `t2` handle the ends of the cylinders.  With this distance function completed, the rest of the computation is straightforward.

```
cylinders = Table[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], RandomReal[5]}, {100}];
nint = ParallelTable[Or @@ Table[int[cylinders[[i]], cylinders[[j]]], {j, i + 1, 100}], 
    {i, 100}];
c = Cases[{cylinders, nint} // Transpose, {z_, False} -> z, {1}];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Directive[Opacity@RandomReal[{.4, .9}], Hue[RandomReal[]]], 
    Cylinder[First@#, Last@#]} & /@ c, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

In this particular run, only `45` of the cylinders remain.  The entire calculation takes only seconds.

Comment: I'm afraid your code thinks that the cylinders `Cylinder[{{-1, 0, 0.1}, {0, 0, 0}}, 1]` and `Cylinder[{{1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0.1}}, 1]` are intersecting. (I had to tilt them slightly otherwise it gave me a 1/0 error.)

Comment: @Rahul  You are correct on both counts.  Collinear axes cause problems, and the intersection criterion at the ends errs on the side of caution.  There probably is a simply way to handle the former.  The latter is deliberate in order to avoid extremely complicated expressions for handling cylinder ends.  I prefer to discard a few too many cylinders.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a solution and certainly not sufficient at all.

The following function can check whether two cylinders intersect or not.

```
   IntCyl[cyl1_, cyl2_] := 
 RegionQ[DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[cyl1, cyl2]] // Quiet]
```

For example

```
c1 = Cylinder[{{1, 1, 1}, {3, 5, 1}}];
c2 = Cylinder[{{-4, 5, 0}, {2, 5, 3}}];
c3 = Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}];
c4 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}];
GraphicsRow@{Graphics3D[{c1, c2}], Graphics3D[{c3, c4}]}
```

[image]

```
IntCyl[c1, c2] // Timing
IntCyl[c3, c4] // Timing
```

> {0.461932, False}
>    {2.11221, True}

An extension to more cylinders is not attractive at all...Even with 10 cylinders Mathematica needs a lot of time.

```
cylinders = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], RandomReal[5]}, {10}];
cylinderslist = Cylinder[First@#, Last@#] & /@ cylinders;
Timing[nint = 
   Table[Or @@ 
     Table[IntCyl[cylinderslist[[i]], cylinderslist[[j]]], {j, i + 1, 
       10}], {i, 10}];]
```

> {142.887, Null}