# non-intersecting cylinders and DiscretizeRegion, RegionIntersection

Tags: regions

This is a sequel to my previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100623/generating-randomly-oriented-non-intersecting-cylinders/100909#100909).

```
IntCyl[cyl1_, cyl2_] := 
 RegionQ[DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[cyl1, cyl2]] // Quiet]

cylinders = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], RandomReal[5]}, {10}];
cylinderslist = Cylinder[First@#, Last@#] & /@ cylinders;
Timing[nint = 
   Table[Or @@ 
     Table[IntCyl[cylinderslist[[i]], cylinderslist[[j]]], {j, i + 1, 
       10}], {i, 10}];]
(*{142.887, Null}*)
```

Is it a way to iprove the performance of the code?

Comment: I wonder if you might be interested in rolling your own intersection function. Determining whether two cylinders intersect is covered well in this document from the documentation of [Geometric Tools](http://www.geometrictools.com/): [Intersection of Cylinders](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionOfCylinders.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, I already know. The reply I got in my previous question is very helpful and it does what I want. The current post has to do more with the perfomance of `DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[cyl1, cyl2]`

Comment: So the function `IntCyl` determines whether two cylinders intersect?  How is it different than the `int` function from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100662/9490)?

Comment: I found the code here: https://m.reddit.com/r/Mathematica/comments/3eic0a/is_regionintersection_broken/?ref=readnext Although, as I said, the reply I got is certainly an excellent one I was wondering if we can achieve the same result (and performance) using directly built-in functions of Mathematica.

Comment: I would be more worried that `IntCyl` [fails a test case](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZG2RYjf4).

Comment: I got it:-)! Thanks a lot. So, I will stick with  the answer I got here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100623/generating-randomly-oriented-non-intersecting-cylinders/100662#100662 and I try to follow the discussion of the afforementioned document from MarcoB. In the meantime, I may hope that @J.M. can elaborate more on his comment here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100623/generating-randomly-oriented-non-intersecting-cylinders?noredirect=1#comment273097_100623