# Intersecting ellipsoids

Tags: geometry, regions

First of all I know that finding whether two ellipsoids intersect is complicated and there are specific algorithms created for this purpose (see, for instance, [[1]](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionOfEllipsoids.pdf). Actually, I am trying to follow this documentation in order to implement something in *Mathematica*. Of course there are [other approaches](http://centerforspace.net/downloads/files/pubs/JGCD.V26.N01.pdf)).

I have "googled" for a while, searching for *Mathematica* codes but I could not find anything relevant.
Maybe this has to do with the fact that functions like `RegionIntersection` were introduced rather recently (2014; version 10.0).

Anyway, here is a simple code. It's not panacea of course. (Found [here](https://m.reddit.com/r/Mathematica/comments/3eic0a/is_regionintersection_broken/?ref=readnext))

```
RegionIntersectQ[e1_, e2_] := 
 RegionQ[DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[e1, e2]] // Quiet]
```

It works in many cases. E.g.

```
Graphics3D[{g1 = 
   Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {{5, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}], 
  g2 = Ellipsoid[{1, 1, 1}, {{10, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}]}, 
 Axes -> True]
RegionIntersectQ[g1, g2] // Timing
(*2.62...,True*)
```

[image]

My first question is about the time efficiency. Why 2.6 sec are needed?

We can find (in version 10.3 at least!) other cases that the code finds correctly whether the two ellipsoids intersect (the code tries harder when there is a tiny region of intersection).

But there are cases where it fails strangely and I do not understand why.

```
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.6], 
   g1 = Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {{5, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}]}, 
  g2 = Ellipsoid[{4.4, 1, 1}, {{10, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 7}}]}, 
 Axes -> True]
RegionIntersectQ[g1, g2] // Timing
```

[image]

I am not expecting other people to spend their time to implement [algorithms of others](http://systemanalysisdpt-cmc-msu.github.io/ellipsoids/) but I am wondering how we can use efficient the current functionality of *Mathematica* (built-in functions like `RegionIntersection`) to check if two ellipsoids intersect or not.

**EDIT**
After writing the question I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100919/discretizeregion-fails-on-two-clearly-intersecting-cylinders)  which has connection with 
my previous question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100913/non-intersecting-cylinders-and-discretizeregion-regionintersection?lq=1).
@JasonB addresses the issue very thoroughly.

But the query remains the same: Can I expect *Mathematica's* relevant functionality to do the job (even with a bit help of us) or should I forget the whole idea?

Comment: Just checking, but you do know RegionIntersection is not implemented for MeshRegion objects embedded in 3D?

Comment: @M.R. I don't see your point. Can you elaborate more on your comment? Thanks.

Comment: Check the docs for ref/RegionIntersection under Possible issues, and it says RegionIntersection functionality in 3d is not complete.

Comment: @M.R. Thanks again. Very interesting. I read a lot of times this documentation page but I didn't pay attention to this! But an `Ellipsoid` seems less complicated than `DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[1, {20, 3}]]` :-)!

Comment: I agree that the reason for the false negative result is the `RegionIntersection`, but the reason for the timing problem is definitely `DiscretizeRegion`, evaluate:  `First /@ {step1 = RegionIntersection[g1, g2]; // AbsoluteTiming, 
  step2 = DiscretizeRegion[step1]; // AbsoluteTiming, 
  step3 = RegionQ[step2]; // AbsoluteTiming}`

Comment: BTW, @dimitris, what are you working on with all these graphics problems?  They are really quite fun and I'm tempted to blow off a days work to implement the algorithms you linked to.

Comment: @JasonB. You are right. But as I said I was wondering if we can use the current functionality of Mathematica for a simple test.

Comment: This is an active research in computational geometry. Do you want to just visualize the ellipsoids and the intersections, or do you want to obtain the equation representing the surface of intersection. Also, do you want to determine if there is an intersection, or the input is always intersecting ellipsoids?  You can also post this question in the Mathematics community.

Comment: @Saurav: I want to determine if there is intersection. No need for analytic expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) is faster:

```
FindInstance[RegionMember[g1, {x, y, z}] && RegionMember[g2, {x, y, z}],
 {x, y, z}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.002422, {{x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}}}  *)

FindInstance[
  RegionMember[
    Ellipsoid[{5, 0, 0}, {{5, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}], {x, y, z}] && RegionMember[
    Ellipsoid[{1, 1, 1}, {{10, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}], {x, y, z}],
  {x, y, z}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.045233, {}}  *)
```

Also,  `Reduce` is faster than the OP's approximate discretizing, but a bit slower than the above in the positive (first) case.

```
Reduce[Exists[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[g1, {x, y, z}] && RegionMember[g2, {x, y, z}]],
 {x, y, z}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.011632, True}  *)

Reduce[Exists[{x, y, z},
   RegionMember[Ellipsoid[{5, 0, 0}, {{5, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}], {x, y, z}] &&
   RegionMember[Ellipsoid[{1, 1, 1}, {{10, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}], {x, y, z}]],
 {x, y, z}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.044602, False}  *)
```

Comment: I saw the answer right now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Starting in M11.1 you can use [`RegionDisjoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDisjoint). Here are the two OP examples:

```
g1 = Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {{5, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}];
g2 = Ellipsoid[{1, 1, 1}, {{10, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}];

RegionDisjoint[g1, g2] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.002053, False}

```
g1 = Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {{5, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}];
g2 = Ellipsoid[{4.4, 1, 1}, {{10, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 7}}];

RegionDisjoint[g1, g2] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.001416, False}

And here is @Michael's disjoint example:

```
r1 = Ellipsoid[{5, 0, 0}, {{5, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}];
r2 = Ellipsoid[{1, 1, 1}, {{10, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}];

RegionDisjoint[r1, r2] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.041539, True}