# Generate $n$ randomly oriented non-intersecting cylinders with fixed radius and length

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, random

This post is in reference to the previous question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100623/generating-randomly-oriented-non-intersecting-cylinders).

How could I adapt the solution given to have the following constraints: fixed radius, fixed length, number of cylinders, and within a specified domain. Issues might arise when too many cylinders are specified for a small volume.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Your question is really too broad. You should describe what you tried and where you are specifically having a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data for the array `cylinder` can be modified by

```
cylinder = Map[(s = Plus @@ (First@#)/2; d = 50 Subtract @@ (First@#)/
    Norm[Subtract @@ (First@#)]; {{s + d, s - d}, Last@#}) &, cylinders];
```

after which the procedure in the referenced question yields

[image]