# How to generate random non-overlapping cylinders of fixed radius and height in a fixed cube?

Tags: graphics3d, random

I have seen these two questions ([first](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101024/generate-n-randomly-oriented-non-intersecting-cylinders-with-fixed-radius-and)) ([second](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100623/generating-randomly-oriented-non-intersecting-cylinders)) which are related to generating non-overlapping cylinders in a cube. I am trying to adapt them to my goal which is to generate random non-overlapping fixed cylinders **(radius=10nm and height=20nm) in a cube of (100*100*100 nm)**.

The number of cylinders would be 20, 40 and 60 for the three cases that I would like to build. This makes the volume fraction in the range of around 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 for the three cases.

Then at the end I would like to export the coordinates of each cylinders (x1,y1,z1) &(x2,y2,z2) in a file.

I have been using the following reference code as an example and trying to modify this.

```
    p1.p1 + p2.p2 - 2 p1.p2
    ((p1.p1 + p2.p2 - 2 p1.p2) /. {p1 -> p1i + dp1 t1, p2 -> p2i + dp2 t2}) // tf // Expand
    (* p1i.p1i - 2 p1i.p2i + p1i.(dp1 t1) - 2 p1i.(dp2 t2) + p2i.p2i + 
       p2i.(dp2 t2) + (dp1 t1).p1i - 2 (dp1 t1).p2i + (dp1 t1).(dp1 t1) - 
       2 (dp1 t1).(dp2 t2) + (dp2 t2).p2i + (dp2 t2).(dp2 t2) *)


    tf[e_] := e /. Dot[z1_ + z2_, z3_ + z4_] -> 
        Dot[z1, z3] + Dot[z2, z3] + Dot[z1, z4] + Dot[z2, z4]

    Map[# /. z_ :> (z /. t1 -> 1) t1^Count[z, t1, 4] &, 
        Map[# /. z_ :> (z /. t2 -> 1) t2^Count[z, t2, 4] &, %]]
    (* t1^2 dp1.dp1 - 2 t1 t2 dp1.dp2 + t1 dp1.p1i - 2 t1 dp1.p2i + t2^2 dp2.dp2 + 
       t2 dp2.p2i + t1 p1i.dp1 - 2 t2 p1i.dp2 + p1i.p1i - 2 p1i.p2i + t2 p2i.dp2 + p2i.p2i *)

FullSimplify[Solve[{D[%, t1] == 0, D[%, t2] == 0}, {t1, t2}], 
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf1}]
(* {{t1 -> (dp2.dp1 (-dp2.p1i + dp2.p2i) + 
       dp2.dp2 (p1i.dp1 - p2i.dp1))/((dp1.dp2)^2 - dp1.dp1 dp2.dp2), 
     t2 -> (dp1.dp1 (-dp2.p1i + dp2.p2i) + 
       dp2.dp1 (p1i.dp1 - p2i.dp1))/((dp1.dp2)^2 - dp1.dp1 dp2.dp2)}} *)

tf1[e_] := e /. Dot[z1_, z2_] -> Dot[z2, z1]

int[cyl1_, cyl2_] := 
    Module[{p1i = cyl1[[1, 1]], dp1 = cyl1[[1, 2]] - cyl1[[1, 1]], r1 = cyl1[[2]], 
        p2i = cyl2[[1, 1]], dp2 = cyl2[[1, 2]] - cyl2[[1, 1]], r2 = cyl2[[2]], 
        loc, t1, t2}, loc = {t1 -> (dp2.dp1 (-dp2.p1i + dp2.p2i) + 
        dp2.dp2 (p1i.dp1 - p2i.dp1))/((dp1.dp2)^2 - dp1.dp1 dp2.dp2), 
        t2 -> (dp1.dp1 (-dp2.p1i + dp2.p2i) + 
        dp2.dp1 (p1i.dp1 - p2i.dp1))/((dp1.dp2)^2 - dp1.dp1 dp2.dp2)};
        (-r2/Norm[dp2] < (t1 /. loc) < 1 + r2/Norm[dp2]) &&
        (-r1/Norm[dp1] < (t2 /. loc) < 1 + r1/Norm[dp1]) && 
        ((t1^2 dp1.dp1 - 2 t1 t2 dp1.dp2 + t1 dp1.p1i - 2 t1 dp1.p2i + t2^2 dp2.dp2 + 
        t2 dp2.p2i + t1 p1i.dp1 - 2 t2 p1i.dp2 + p1i.p1i - 2 p1i.p2i + t2 p2i.dp2 +
        p2i.p2i) /. loc) < (r1 + r2)^2]

cylinders = Table[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {2, 3}], RandomReal[5]}, {100}];
nint = ParallelTable[Or @@ Table[int[cylinders[[i]], cylinders[[j]]], {j, i + 1, 100}], 
    {i, 100}];
c = Cases[{cylinders, nint} // Transpose, {z_, False} -> z, {1}];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Directive[Opacity@RandomReal[{.4, .9}], Hue[RandomReal[]]], 
    Cylinder[First@#, Last@#]} & /@ c, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 800]
```

Any heads up would be helpful.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Could you check this one? It's almost the same one you did before.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited to Improve Definition of `cylinders`**

This problem differs from the two referenced in the question in three important ways.  The cylinders are precisely confined within a box, the filling factor is much larger, and the aspect ratio of the cylinders is essentially unity.  With perfect ordering, `125` cylinders can fit into the box.  As soon as only a few are placed randomly, the maximum number of remaining cylinders that fit drops precipitously.  To take these considerations into account, `int` (which determines whether two cylinders are non-overlapping) was modified from the referenced answers.

```
int[cyl1_, cyl2_] := Module[{p1i = cyl1[[1, 1]], dp1 = cyl1[[1, 2]] - cyl1[[1, 1]], 
    r1 = cyl1[[2]], p2i = cyl2[[1, 1]], dp2 = cyl2[[1, 2]] - cyl2[[1, 1]], 
    r2 = cyl2[[2]], loc, t1, t2}, 
    loc = {t1 -> Clip[(dp2.dp1 (-dp2.p1i + dp2.p2i) + dp2.dp2 (p1i.dp1 - p2i.dp1))/
    ((dp1.dp2)^2 - dp1.dp1 dp2.dp2), {- r1/Norm[dp1], 1 + r1/Norm[dp1]}], 
           t2 -> Clip[(dp1.dp1 (-dp2.p1i + dp2.p2i) + dp2.dp1 (p1i.dp1 - p2i.dp1))/
    ((dp1.dp2)^2 - dp1.dp1 dp2.dp2), {- r2/Norm[dp2], 1 + r2/Norm[dp2]}]}; 
    ((t1^2 dp1.dp1 - 2 t1 t2 dp1.dp2 + t1 dp1.p1i - 2 t1 dp1.p2i + t2^2 dp2.dp2 + 
    t2 dp2.p2i + t1 p1i.dp1 - 2 t2 p1i.dp2 + p1i.p1i - 2 p1i.p2i + t2 p2i.dp2 + 
    p2i.p2i) /. loc) > 2 (r1 + r2)^2]
```

Note that this function is only approximate and occasionally determines that two cylinders overlap when they do not.  A precise determination could be obtained from

```
Volume@RegionIntersection[Cylinder @@ cylinders[[i]], Cylinder @@ cylinders[[j]]] == 0
```

but is orders of magnitude slower than `int`.  The number of falsely excluded cylinders is not large.  In addition, a second function is introduced to identify and eliminate cylinders that extend slightly beyond the `100 x 100 x 100` box.  It is exact and quite fast.

```
inb[cyl_] := Module[{cos, d, rl = Last[cyl], hlf = Norm[cyl[[1, 1]] - cyl[[1, 2]]]/2},
    And @@ Map[(cos = (cyl[[1, 1, #]] - cyl[[1, 2, #]])/(2 hlf); 
    d = hlf Abs[cos] + rl Sqrt[1 - cos^2]; 
    (-50 + d < (cyl[[1, 1, #]] + cyl[[1, 2, #]])/2 < 50 - d)) &, {1, 2, 3}]]
```

The code to determine the non-overlapping cylinders then is,

```
(SeedRandom[1492]; ict = 2000000; rl = 10; hlf = 10; n = 60;
cylinders = Table[s = RandomReal[{-50 + rl, 50 - rl}, {3}]; zz = RandomReal[{-hlf, hlf}]; 
    phi = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}]; 
    {{s - {Sqrt[hlf^2 - zz^2] Cos[phi], Sqrt[hlf^2 - zz^2] Sin[phi], zz}, 
      s + {Sqrt[hlf^2 - zz^2] Cos[phi], Sqrt[hlf^2 - zz^2] Sin[phi], zz}}, rl}, ict];
cylinders = Pick[cylinders, inb /@ cylinders];
c = {cylinders[[1]]};
Do[If[(And @@ Table[int[cylinders[[i]], c[[j]]], {j, Length[c]}]) && (Length[c] < n), 
    AppendTo[c, cylinders[[i]]]], {i, 2, Length[cylinders]}];
Length[c]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {2412.55, 16} *)

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Directive[Opacity@RandomReal[{.4, .9}], Hue[RandomReal[]]], 
   Cylinder @@ #} & /@ c, ImageSize -> 800, PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}]
```

[image]

Although some cylinders in the figure may appear to be overlap, rotating the figure within Mathematica shows that they are not.  Significantly increasing the number of randomly placed cylinders will be difficult unless `rl` is decreased.

**Result for `rl == hlf == 7`.**

Reducing `rl` and `hlf` to `7` nearly triples the number of non-overlapping cylinders obtained, although slowly.

```
(* {6881.68, 45} *)
```

[image]

**Result for 2:1 aspect ratio**

At the request of the OP in a comment below, the code above has been modified modestly to accommodate independent values for the cylinder radius, `rl`, and half length, `hlf`.  Choosing

```
ict = 10000; rl = 5; hlf = 10; n = 60
```

and the code otherwise as above yields

```
(* {29.1495, 42} *)
```

[image]

**Minor Addition**

At the OP's request, the parameter `n` has been added to the code above.  It specifies the maximum number of non-overlapping cylinders to be generated.  Of course, fewer may be generated, depending on the values of the other parameters, `ict`, `rl`, and `hlf`.

Comment: I am having a hard time putting together the whole code. Some error pops out when I attach everything. The pictures you generated are pretty much what I am looking for. Do you know, how export the co-ordinates in a text file (x1,y1,z1) & (x2,y2,z2)?

Comment: I found and fixed a typo in `inb`.  The simplest way to export the cylinder data as text is `Export["C:\\Temp\\cyls.txt", c]`, where the first argument is the location to which the data is to be exported.  By the way, I now know how to make `int` exact, which will permit a few more cylinders to be packed into the box.  It will take me a while to implement the code.  Please do not forget to upvote and accept my answer, if it meets your needs.

Comment: What does (* {29.8132, 78} *) mean? I know 78 is the number of cylinders. What does 29.81 mean, is it time?
Also, ict value of 5000, do you think it should be 500000?

Comment: The code runs now, however I can see multiple overlapping cylinders in mathematica. Is it something to do with the int or inb function? In addition, Is there a way we could incorporate a input parameter "n", which decides the number of cylinders inside the cube?

Comment: I am not looking for high packing fractions. So, a reasonable "n" would be useful. At the end, I would have a code that could generate random non-overlapping cylinders with specified aspect ratio and specified number. Could you show how to add n?

Comment: Is something wrong with the code? I tried to run them for n=42, ict = 5000, r1=5 and hlf = 30. I am getting errors.

Comment: @skonda2  The code had been tuned for cylinders with aspect ratios of order unity, as originally requested in the question.  I have now modified the code for more general aspect ratios, as a result of which the number of cylinders generated is a bit less.  Note also that I have rescaled `ict`.  I should add that I now know how to improve the code efficiency but will not have time to do so for a few weeks.

Comment: When I run the above code in mathematica, I could see see overallping cylinders. The conditions were n = 42, ict = 2000000, r1=5 and hlf = 30.

Comment: @skonda2  Replacing `> 2 (r1 + r2)^2` by `> 9 (r1 + r2)^2` in `int` eliminates the intersecting cylinders.  But, it is not very efficient.  Remember, though, that your question related to cylinders with aspect ratios of order unity, and that is the question I successfully answered.  You should not expect the same approach to work well for high aspect ratios.  In fact, I now do know how to eliminate intersecting cylinders with high efficiency no matter what the aspect ratio, but I shall not have time to code it for a few weeks.

Comment: @bbgodgrey I understand I may have added a lot of additional constraints. I will modify the question in edits. I have marked the answer as correct, since it does most of the things. Feel free to improve the code as and when you get time.