# Random 3D cylinders plot

Tags: random

I have seen this trivial example for circles

```
n = 5;
r = 0.2;
Table[pt[i] = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], {i, 1, n}];
Graphics[{Table[Circle[pt[i], r], {i, n}]}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

I would like to draw Random 3D plot of Cylinders with fix height and radius.
Best Regards
Danny

Comment: related:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100623/9490

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be marked as a duplicate, but the answer to that post is more complicated because of the constraint that the cylinders do not intersect.  For this question, just create one cylinder with the right length and radius and rotate and translate it randomly,

```
radius = .3;
length = 5;
cyl = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, length}}, radius];
cylinder := 
 cyl // Rotate[#, RandomReal[{0, 2 π}], RandomReal[1, 3]] & // 
  Translate[#, RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 3]] &

Graphics3D@Table[cylinder, {50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 5; r = 0.2; pt = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}]
Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{#[[1]], #[[2]], 0}, {#[[1]], #[[2]], 1}}, r] & /@ pt]
```

If you want more

```
n = 5; r = 0.2;
pt1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
pt2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
Graphics3D[Cylinder[{pt1[[#]], pt2[[#]]}, r] & /@ Range[n]]
```

[image]